# Access local USB devices from a remote PC via remote desktop?

Tags: windows, usb, remote-desktop

Is it possible for local USB devices to be accessed via a remote PC through remote desktop? Is there software or other configuration that can be done to support this? More specifically, I'm referring to the ability to access any USB device rather than just a flash drive. For example, I'd like the ability to plug in a USB smart card or fingerprint reader and have the remote PC recognize the device.

Comment: What do you mean by "Accessed"? To copy files over remote desktop, browse the contents, what? Also the explanation is a little vague.

Comment: Added some more details.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes and no.

If you are talking about USB flash drives, it is possible and share them as a hard drive.

The same goes with a few compatible Plug and Play devices, but not everything.

Open remote desktop (Mstsc) and click the "Local Resources" tab, then click "More" under the "Local devices and resources" section.

From here, you should be able to set what is shared from your local machine to the remote.

[image]

Comment: My question is actually more generic than just flash drives. For example, like a USB smart card reader or fingerprint reader.

Comment: Take a look at the picture!  Typically, Smart card reader will get understood by your local computer as such, and you can simply send the smart card over by ticking that option. For other devices, there is no one answer fits all - You just have to plug in and see if it shows up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using *Microsoft Remote Desktop* app for MacOS, settings for redirecting locally connected devices to a remote machine is similar to the Windows app.

When adding a new connection or editing an existing one, **open the *Devices & Audio* tab and simply check what types of locally connected devices or services you want to redirect**. You cannot control individual devices, unfortunately. There're the following options (in version 10.4.1 of the app):

- Printers
- Smart cards
- Clipboard
- Microphone
- Cameras

[image: Redirect settings of the Microsoft Remote Desktop for MacOS]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able using windows remote desktop, but it works using Remmina, I used it on linux but it probably works from windows too,

###### Linux instructions:

1. run remmina as root
2. you can find the usb details with:

   `lsusb`
3. edit your remmina connection, go to advanced, scroll down to usb redirection add the usb details in this format:

   `id:<PID>:<VID>,addr:<BUS>:<DEVICE>`

this works with any usb device