# Access local usb from a remote windows desktop

Tags: windows, usb, remote-desktop

I would like to access my local usb devices (phones) from a remote machine.
The remote machine is used to build / compile mobile app.

I followed this topic : [Access local USB devices from a remote PC via remote desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/49285/access-local-usb-devices-from-a-remote-pc-via-remote-desktop)
Before enter in my remote desktop I can enabled all my usb devices but when entered in the remote desktop, i can't see any devices...

Both machines (client / host) are on windows 10, ethernet lan.

Can you help me ?

Comment: I would suggest *starting with* a search for `RemoteFX USB redirection android`.  I believe that you will need to probably enable this via Group Policy before knowing if it will fail or not.  Also, please clarify your question to what accessing your phone MEANS.  It is difficult to answer otherwise.  File System?  Debugging?  What?

Comment: Okay, i will try.
I would access my phones to build app and develop on them for example.

Comment: I've already enabled group policy for Remote FX @SeñorCMasMas

Comment: I plug some headset, usb storage, mouse, keyboard : on windows remote config i well enabled them in the share option but on the remote laptop, i can't see them...

Comment: I will try to upgrade the remote laptop from education to pro, maybe it's just that.

Comment: Probably not.  For most android devices (from my experience, not saying this is TRUE).. they either show up with a virtual COM port for debugging, or have a custom USB driver provided by the manufacturer (like LG).  You are probably not going to have a whole lot of luck this way.  Figure out if your device uses a COM port.. you *might* be able to use another technology to remote the COM port independent of RDC.